# how to count hourly accum and make dataframe by date index and 0h~23h columns using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I would like to get the cumulative value over time(resampling 0:00 ~23:00) with the data below.

and also make a dataFrame by **date** index and **0h to 23h** columns

how can i do?

**before**

```
                    sum
timestamp   
2018-01-02 09:57:03  1

2018-01-02 12:14:16  1

2018-01-02 12:43:34  1

2018-01-02 12:56:29  1

2018-01-02 14:14:08  1

... ...
```

**after**

```
             0h  1h  2h  3h  4h  5h  6h  7h  8h  9h 10h 11h 12h 13h 14h 15h 16h 17h 18h 19h 20h 21h 22h 23h

date    

2018-01-02    0  1  1  1  0  0  1  2  1  8 12 22 25 30 21 11 8  2  0  0  0  0  0  0      

2018-01-03    0 1  1  1  0  0  1  2  1  8 21 10  7 13 12 11 0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  

2018-01-04    0  1  1  1  0  0  1  2  1  3  4 10  8  4  0  0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0     

2018-01-05    0  1  1  1  0  0  1  2  1  8  1  0  5  4  3  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

... ...

Comment: What have you tried? How did it go wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) with [`DatetimeIndex.date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.date.html) and [`DatetimeIndex.hour`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.hour.html), then [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) and last [`DdfataFrame.add_suffix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_suffix.html):

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

df = (df.pivot_table(index=df.index.date, columns=df.index.hour, values='sum', aggfunc='sum')
        .reindex(range(24), axis=1, fill_value=0)
        .add_suffix('h'))
print (df)
timestamp   0h  1h  2h  3h  4h  5h  6h  7h  8h  9h  10h  11h  12h  13h  14h  \
2018-01-02   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1    0    0    3    0    1   

timestamp   15h  16h  17h  18h  19h  20h  21h  22h  23h  
2018-01-02    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
```